# Check tree - pass parametr to not check children

Tags: angularjs

I have this code http://plnkr.co/edit/kiH0Ge?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <choice-tree ng-model="myTree" children="true"></choice-tree>
  <hr />
  $scope.myTree = {{myTree | json}}
</body>
</html>
```

I've added parametr checkChildren

```
<choice-tree ng-model="myTree" checkChildren="true"></choice-tree>
```

Then in check directive I want to run function conditionally

```
if(scope.checkChildren === 'true') 
   checkChildren(choice);
```

But it doesn't work.

I know there is isolated scope, but how to build tree then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now everything works http://plnkr.co/edit/5lLGIQ?p=preview

I just changed children to withchildren and this (crucial)

```
$compile('<choice-tree ng-model="choice.children" children="{{children}}"></choice-tree>')(scope);
```

to

```
$compile('<choice-tree ng-model="choice.children" withchildren="'+scope.withchildren+'"></choice-tree>')(scope);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5lLGIQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, I think it is a simple typo.
With a little modification, it seems to be working:  http://plnkr.co/edit/BJqsl3

You want to check bool value, e.g. `scope.checkChildren === true`  not against `'true'`

### [edit] It seems I did not understand the spec correctly

If I remove the `if` statement which I pointed out above, and call
`checkChildren()`, it works.
Is this what you intend?
Plunk is updated accordingly.

Comment: But it doesn't work as expected. If children is true and check, it should check also children. When uncheck it should uncheck all children.

Comment: Then you do not need `if` condition, just call `checkChildren()` unconditionary.  I updated the plunk.